# Scala - Cleaner way of writing generic numeric operation method

Tags: scala

Is there a cleaner way of writing this method? Preferably, I wouldn't need to match against all valid Types and instead permit every Type that has the * method. Also, is there a way to not require `asInstanceOf[T]` at the end?

```
def expr_neg[T <: AnyVal](value: T): T = value match {
  case int: Int => (int * -1).asInstanceOf[T]
  case long: Long => (long * -1).asInstanceOf[T]
  case float: Float => (float * -1).asInstanceOf[T]
  case double: Double => (double * -1).asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

Comment: If you are interested in numerical computations using scala, you should check out http://github.com/non/spire.  It contains a much richer set of typeclasses than just numeric.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would be much better off using the Numeric Typeclass:

```
  def exprNeg[T:Numeric](value: T): T = {
    val n = implicitly[Numeric[T]]
    n.negate(value)
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to @melps answer, it is also possible to use the arithmetic operators provided by `Numeric.Implicits`:

```
import Numeric.Implicits._

def f[T: Numeric](x: T) = -x
```

Which is pretty cool, but unfortunately never mentioned in the Scala docs. This also works for `Ordering`:

```
import Ordering.Implicits._

def g[T: Ordering](x: T) = x < x
```