# Scala - arithmetic operations on params of type Any

Tags: scala, type-conversion

I am looking to define a function that takes two args of type Any and attempts to add them, like this:

```
def plus(x:Any,y:Any):Try[Any] = {
   ...
}
```

yielding Success if the operands are of types that can be added (arithmetically, not string concat or anything like that), and Failure if not.  For example:

```
val x:Any = 1
val y:Any = 2
val z = plus(x,y) // z = Success(3)
```

or

```
val x:Any = "wrong"
val y:Any = 2
val z = plus(x,y) // z = Failure(...)
```

and, I would like to have type promotion work as it normally does with addition: Int + Int => Int, Int + Double => Double, etc.

I know there must be a clever and terse way to do this, without having to check every possible combination of types with a match.  I'm pretty new (only a week) to Scala so would appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Scala - Cleaner way of writing generic numeric operation method](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31346087/scala-cleaner-way-of-writing-generic-numeric-operation-method)

Comment: @Leugg - it wasn't that.  I had a double problem.  The first is to do dispatch on the actual parameters (at compile time the types will always be Any) and then to have the arithmetic function act as it would as if the compiler knew the types dynamically.  So I want plus(1, 2.0) to yield a Double and plus(1, 2) to yield an Int

Comment: Oh, in this case, i doubt there is a simple and clean way to do what you want. By using `Any` you cancel the type system. Are you sure you are bound to `Any` or is there a way to keep the original types? It seems like you are trying to use Scala like a dynamic types language.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it - I don't have any way (that I know of) to keep the type information around.  I'm working on a relational query language to compile down to operations on Apache Spark.  The relations are being represented as RDDs of arrays.  It would be better if I could keep schema information around but I don't know how I'd exploit that any more effectively than just doing the dynamic type checks in Scala - I'm still left with the dispatch to do.

Answer (score 1):

In your samples you know type of arguments at compile time. In this case you can do a better job using type system:

```
scala> def plus[T: Numeric](a: T, b: T) = implicitly[Numeric[T]].plus(a, b)
plus: [T](a: T, b: T)(implicit evidence$1: Numeric[T])T

scala> plus(1, 2)
res0: Int = 3

scala> plus(1, 2.5)
res1: Double = 3.5

scala> plus(1, "2")
<console>:9: error: could not find implicit value for evidence parameter of type Numeric[Any]
              plus(1, "2")
                  ^
```

Comment: thanks for the reply.  I made a mistake when I gave the examples and failed to type the arguments explicitly as Any.  You should be able to see the problem more clearly now.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**: Oops! I missed the last part of your question. What I explained doesn't work if you try to add two different types such as `Int + Double => Double`.

---

I think you can use [Scalaz](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz)'s Monoid

Simply, it looks something like this

```
trait Monoid[F] extends Semigroup[F] {
  def zero: F
  def append(f1: F, f2: => F): F
}
```

So if you want to use it, all you need to do is importing Scalaz

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
```

Then you can simply do

```
1 |+| 1        // result: 2

"a" |+| "b"    // result: ab

BigInt(100) |+| BigInt(100)    // BigInt(200)
```

Scalaz provides implicit type conversion for most known types like Int, BigInt, BigDecimal, String, etc., but if you have your own type and you want to make it appendable, you can do it easily.

Let's say you have a type like

```
case class Something(value: Int)
```

You can use implicit type conversion like.

```
  implicit def SomethingMonoid = new Monoid[Something] {
    override def zero: Something = Something(0)
    override def append(f1: Something, f2: => Something): Something = Something(f1.value |+| f2.value)  // you can even use |+| here as value is Int
  }
```

Now, you can just do

```
Something(10) |+| Something(100)    // result: Something(110)
```

If you want to reuse it, just import that SomethingMonoid with Scalaz

```
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._
import your.package.SomethingMonoid

// Or
import scalaz._
import Scalaz._

// ...
val somethingMonoid = your.package.SomethingMonoid
```

Then you can do

```
Something(111) |+| Something(222)    // result: Something(333)
```

Using Monoid to handle the result is better than having your method and return Try[T] because you don't get compile time type safety whereas Monoid will give you a compile-time error if you do something like,

```
Something(10) |+| 100    // a compile-time error
```

If you really want to have your own plus, you can do something like this

```
def plus[T](x: T, y: T)(implicit monoid: Monoid[T]): Try[T] = Try(monoid.append(x, y))
```

with Scalaz as I explained above, yet you will get a compile-time error when types don't match so no point to use Try unless computation may throw some exception.

```
plus(1, 2)        // result: 3
plus(Something(1), Something(9))    // result: Something(10)
plus("one", 2)    // result: a compile-time error
```